# Overload help method in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

for some reason I am asked to see if it possible to override the /help method of a service to return custom data instead. Currently I have a calling url like this one

> http://{myDomain}/CRM/Customers.svc/json/help

Which returns all methods available

[image: see here]

I tried something like this in my serviceContract, but I can't access to my method, is it possible ?

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/help", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void GetInformations();
```

Thanks

Comment: Should the signature be public instead private?

Comment: The interface for the ServiceContract is public so there is no trouble of visibility I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Balaji I dig a bit more and was able to make it work in a slightly different way.
I applied a custom behaviorConfiguration to my service and in it I disabled the help, see below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="{myDomain}.CRM.Customers">
            <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" bindingConfiguration="" contract="{contract}"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="false"/>
            </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: i've used single configuration in my page. for your requirement refer to the document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx as same as you did.

Comment: Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

By default in web.config help page is enabled in the web http endpoint. To override it you could set as false, then your override method will be triggered.

```
  <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- TIP: Enable automatic XML/JSON support -->
        <!-- TIP: Enable service help page -->
        <standardEndpoint automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="false"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be what I need, I added this in the web.config in the system.serviceModel node

<standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="false"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

but it does not change the help page from appearing, am I missing something ?

Bonus point : I have mutliples services configured in the web.config, is it possible to apply this modification only to the service I need ?